# OpenCV: "[ WARN:0] terminating async callback" when attempting to take a picture

Tags: python, image, opencv, webcam, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to take a picture from the defualt carmera with python, to do this I am using openCV (`import cv2 as cv` from python shell). However, when I attempt to disable the camera it closes but with the error `[ WARN:0] terminating async callback`.

This is code I am trying to run:

```py
import cv2 as cv

camera_port = 0
camera = cv.VideoCapture(camera_port)
return_value, image = camera.read()
cv.imwrite("image.png", image)

camera.release() # Error is here
```

The code outputs the desired result, it takes and saves an image, but I do not understand *why* the error message occurs or how to *remove* it

Comment: For whoever is looking for the reason, as Aprajita Verma mentioned, the handle to the webcam is not released which gives the error. I have used the webcam in and outside of a condition in my code for OCR application. When the handle is released, the error does not occur.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same warning.

Just modify the line

```py
camera = cv.VideoCapture(camera_port)
```

to

```py
camera = cv.VideoCapture(camera_port, cv.CAP_DSHOW)
```

Comment: This solution worked but defining port instead `cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`

Comment: Using ``cv2.CAP_DSHOW`` removes the warning, but slows down my frame rate from 30fps to 7fps, on Windows.

Comment: Correct Answer, don't know why, but mentioning the 2nd parameter solves the warning

Comment: Goodness! Thank you so much!

Comment: It's worth noting that DirectShow is a legacy API and is currently deprecated

Comment: @Goigle what would you use instead of `CAP_DSHOW`?

Comment: @PeterWood The default on windows should be fine (`CAP_MSMF`), assuming your Win10 is up to date. On Win10 20H2 I experience no issues (that warning just means the stream ended). The only people on my team who have issues are on outdated versions of Windows. This makes sense as DSHOW used to be the default and MSMF is slowly replacing DSHOW

Comment: `destroyAllWindows()` is absolutely _not_ relevant to this question.

Answer (score 7):

```
camera = cv.VideoCapture(camera_port, cv.CAP_DSHOW)

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Using cv2.CAP_DSHOW removes the warning, but slows down my frame rate from 30fps to 7fps, on Windows

Comment: bad answer. `destroyAllWindows` has nothing to do with cameras, and there are no windows to destroy. do not just copy a previous answer and repost it.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably showing a warning because you're not releasing the handle to the webcam.

try adding this to the end of the code

```
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: On Windows 10 with Python 3.8 and OpenCV 4.2, this does not solve the problem. The warning is also displayed on the OpenCV sample programs, e.g. ``samples/python/video.py``.

Answer (score 4):

I did this & I don't see that warning there after.(only for Windows OS)

Open cmd and type:

```
setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in MSMF backend of opencv.

If you are using windows then you can change the backend to `DirectShow` backend.

So, change `VideoCapture` like this:

```
captureDevice = cv.VideoCapture(0, cv.CAP_DSHOW)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as indicated *Sumit Kumar*

```
camera_port = 0
#camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not camera.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

return_value, image = camera.read()
print("We take a picture of you, check the folder")
cv2.imwrite("image.png", image)

camera.release() # Error is here
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: bad answer. `destroyAllWindows` has nothing to do with cameras, and there are no windows to destroy. do not just copy a previous answer and repost it.

Answer (score -1):

1. first:add `cv.destroyAllWindows()`
2. second:the camera permission you have banned,and then check it.

Comment: bad answer. `destroyAllWindows` has nothing to do with cameras, and there are no windows to destroy. do not just copy a previous answer and repost it.

Answer (score -1):

```
camera = cv.VideoCapture(camera_port, cv.CAP_DSHOW) # Added cv.CAP_DSHOW
return_value, image = camera.read()
cv.imwrite("image.png", image)
camera.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows() # Handles the releasing of the camera accordingly
```

Comment: bad answer. `destroyAllWindows` has nothing to do with cameras, and there are no windows to destroy. do not just copy a previous answer and repost it.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

hey guys found the solution pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.7.28 try like this we have to specifically say the version try lesser version mine was 4.x so I did and no error popped up

Comment: that only does something because the **older** version doesn't have the new MSMF API, which emits this _warning_