# OpenCV returns an Array of All Zeros on video.read

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ffmpeg

Below is the relevant code

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

video = cv.VideoCapture(0) #tells obj to use built in camera\

#create a face cascade object 
face_cascade  = 
cv.CascadeClassifier(r"C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- 
packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml")

a = 1
#create loop to display a video
while True:
    a = a + 1
    check, frame = video.read()
    print(frame)

    #converts to a gray scale img
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #create the faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

    for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print(x, y, w, h)

    #show the image
    cv.imshow('capturing', gray)

    key = cv.waitKey(1) #gen a new frame every 1ms

    if key == ord('q'): #once you enter 'q' the loop will be exited
        break

print(a) #this will print the number of frames

#captures the first frame
video.release() #end the web cam

#destroys the windows when you are not defined
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code displays a video captured from my webcam camera. Despite that, OpevCV doesn't seem to be processing any frames as all the frames look like this

```
 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

which I assume means that they are empty.

This I believe is preventing the algorithm from being able to detect my face in the frame. I have a feeling that the issue lies in the ffmpeg codec, but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed even if that is the case.

OS: Windows 10
Language: Python

EDIT: The Frame is not empty but all the values in the array seem to be '0'

Why is the frame empty and how can I get OpenCV to detect my face in the frame?

Comment: I would suggest rewording your question---all zeros is not an empty frame, but a completely black frame. An "empty" frame would be more akin to getting `None` for your `frame`, instead of a black image. Are you getting this for every frame? How are you opening the video capture device? You've left that part of your code out.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds That first part is correct and I will reword it. But this is the extent of the code that I wrote for this project. I do not know much about what is going on in the backend.

Comment: Sorry, your code section scrolls for like 3 lines and I didn't realize it scrolled, thought you left the top bit out. Are you sure that `0` corresponds to your webcam? If you have multiple cameras connected to your computer, it might be `1` or `2`...etc. Otherwise, be sure that you can grab webcam feed on your computer outside of OpenCV and that it looks correct. If everything is fine but OpenCV just has black images, I would look into re-installing OpenCV, building from source if possible.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I think it does because when I run my code, it opens up the front facing in built camera.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the image cannot be read, so cv2 return an empty matrix, you need to make sure that the frame isn't empty.

```
...
while True:
    a += 1
    check, frame = video.read()
    if not check or frame.empty():
        continue
    ...
```

Comment: It seems like the image cannot be read. I am not sure why this is.

Comment: Do you get only empty frames ?

Comment: Yes I only get those empty frames.@Alakazam

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this happens if you are using Windows 
I came up with the solution after having this warning

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888878/cv2-warn0-terminating-async-callback-when-attempting-to-take-a-picture)

```
video = cv.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

According to the documentation cv2.CAP_DSHOW refers to Direct Show which is a multimedia framework and API to perform various operations with media files or streams.

There's an example in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html)

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: According to the documentation cv2.CAP_DSHOW refers to Direct Show which is a multimedia framework and API to perform various operations with media files or streams.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are able to connect to the camera

```
...
while True:
    a = a + 1
    if video.isOpened():
        check, frame = video.read()
        print(frame)
    ...
```

Comment: I am able to connect to the camera, it just seems to not be reading the frames

Answer (score 0):

I think this due to the Antivirus. Try disabling it.