# "[ WARN:0] global SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback" warning

Tags: opencv

I'm getting a warning while trying to run the following code. I have added the cv.destroyAllWindows() function as well. The warning is still showing.

```
import cv2 as cv
import datetime

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,1280)
cap.set(4,720)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        text = "Width: "+str(cap.get(3))+" Height: "+str(cap.get(4))
        datet = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        frame = cv.putText(frame, datet, (10, 50), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv.LINE_AA)
        frame = cv.circle(frame, (640, 360), 200, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv.LINE_AA)
        cv.imshow("frame", frame)

        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888878/cv2-warn0-terminating-async-callback-when-attempting-to-take-a-picture)

using `cap = cv.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

For fellow googlers, for whom the accepted answer is not working and is getting an error like this:

```
anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

The fix is downgrading the opencv version to `3.4.2.16`

Do:

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16
```