# The exact same Python code as the instructor video shows running fails on my pc with a warning

Tags: python, opencv, video, webcam, capture

A Python instructional video shows a simple example of cv2.VideoCapture(0) working, but on my PC it fails to open the camera and run.
**Here's the code:**

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

video.release()
```

**The error message is here:**

```
[ WARN:0@5.031] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007427/cv2-warn0-global-cap-msmf-cpp-674-sourcereadercbsourcereadercb-termina and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596748/warn0-global-sourcereadercbsourcereadercb-terminating-async-callback-wa

Comment: that's merely a warning. where is the complete traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the error and found the following post: [CV2: "[ WARN:0] terminating async callback" when attempting to take a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53888878/12131013)

Try adding `cv2.CAP_DSHOW` to your VideoCapture call, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56839757/12131013

```py
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
video.release()
```