# cv2: [ WARN:0] global cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

**Full warning message:**

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

---

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

captureDevice = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #captureDevice = camera

while True:
    ret, frame = captureDevice.read() 

    cv2.imshow('my frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

captureDevice.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**Description:**
When it runs, the `my frame` windows appear and when I terminate the code, it gives me that warning message.

```
Python: 3.7.4
OpenCV (cv2): 4.1.2
OS: Windows 10
```

---

I don't know to fix this warning and why it gets me. Hope you help me in fixing and understanding that.
In addition, answers of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888878/cv2-warn0-terminating-async-callback-when-attempting-to-take-a-picture) didn't help me anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using your code I'm not getting any errors

Comment: @nathancy Thank you for the response. With the same version of `python` and `cv2`?

Comment: Windows 10, `OpenCV 4.1.0.25`, `Python 3.7.4`

Comment: @M.Rostami Have you had time to review the answers? Up vote the ones that helped you and click on the checkbox near the answer that solved the problem. By doing these things you will be helping future visitors find their answers.

Answer (score 47):

This seems to be a bug in MSMF backend of opencv. You can see more details in [this issue](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/198).

I don't think this problem exists on Linux platforms. So I am providing the solution for windows.

### Windows only solution

For windows platform, you can change the backend to something else (most preferably DirectShow backend. For this, add to your `VideoCapture` like below:

```
captureDevice = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #captureDevice = camera
```

This works for `OpenCV>=3.4`.

Comment: Equivalent code in C# for reference: 

`using var capture = new VideoCapture(0, VideoCapture.API.DShow)`

Comment: This indeed avoids the warning, although I verify in my code that DSHOW was being automatically selected by OpenCV in my setup even without having specifically specified cv2.CAP_DHOW so explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

A **warning** message is not an **error**!

But if that bothers you so much, you might try to disable MSMF by setting the following Environment Variable to `0` on Windows:

```
OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF
```

[How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it but the warning message still here.

Comment: Just remember that after changing an environment variable, you must close and reopen the application that is used to launch your OpenCV code.

Comment: In my case, adding this envi. variable in windows, I can access the video stream faster and without warning. Unfortunately, after this, I can't use function from cv2.VideoCapture(0) such cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)...